# How do I get a free developer license for the SDL Tridion site?

Tags: licensing

SDL App Developer hub has the following description.
"Our developer hub provides:Free developer license for SDL Tridion Sites"

In addition, although FAQs is described as "Please visit the Developer Hub where you can request a free developer license, there is a form at the bottom of the page.", the form is not found.

This question uses a machine translation.
I'm sorry for the bad English.

Answer (score 5):

There was a SDL Tridion Developer License program (that I created and was in charge of) for a few years, but this program was discontinued in 2020.

I think the only way to get a developer-style license today is to contact Customer Support at https://gateway.sdl.com and for that you may need an existing support contract.

PS: My current position at SDL is in no way linked to Tridion Development or Product Management, and therefore I cannot possibly comment on the reasons why this program was dropped.

Comment: Then information must be updated on Tridion own website. Statements written over are misleading.